# How do I find a keyframe in a transport stream?

Tags: video-streaming, transport-stream

I wrote a program that will parse a transport stream. But I need to know if a transport stream packet contains an i-frame. What is the best way to do this? I heard somewhere that I need to look at a couple of bits after the picture start code but I don't know where to find this in the TS packet.

Answer (score 3):

http://dvd.sourceforge.net/dvdinfo/mpeghdrs.html

This is a brief overview of the headers. In the picture header you'll find the frame type.

http://www.pjdaniel.org.uk/mpeg/

This is a nice tool to inspect one packet at a time and it displays some header codes.